# Firestore Timestamp format in android vs firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my platform firestore timestamp is in

> t : April 7, 2020 at 12:07:16 PM UTC+5:30

which is created by an android client using the following code :

```
createdAt = new Timestamp(new Date());
```

trying to create the above date format from inside a firebase cloud function but it returns the date in below format

> t : "2020-04-07T20:35:08.717Z"

using code

```
t: new Date().toISOString()
```

also tried

```
Firestore.Timestamp.now();
```

can someone please assist as to how to get date in the same format as the one in android

exact code is object population in cloud function and returns the time in the above incompatible format

```
let messagePayload = {
          msg:"A test message",
          mt:"text",
          pm:"",
          pmdi:"",
          sb:"1908392XXXX",
          sdi:"Ichthyocentaurs",
          t: new Date().toISOString() 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you see on Android is highly specific to the locale where the device is configured to run, and this will vary wildly depending on the language and timezone.  This default string format generally should not be used for anything other than debugging purposes.

The format you see with JavaScript is meant to transmit dates formatted as strings, to be shared between systems, and not for display.

If you want a specific date format in JavaScript, I strongly suggest making use of some library or utility to format dates and times as you see fit, in a predictable way.  JavaScript does not have any "good" date formatting capabilities built into it.  Instead consider using something like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to specify exactly the string format you want.

For your specific case, if you're trying to send a date to an android client app, I would also strongly urge you to **not** format that on the backend, and instead use the date formatting utilities built into the Android platform (such as [DateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat)).  The default Java date string format is almost certainly not what you want.  You will be able to format the date using the locale provided on the Android device, which is what the user will likely prefer, based on their settings.